# Rails 3.1 subdomain based controller routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently getting the error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/tenant_admin"
```

I was using something like:
http://example.com/accounts/1/tenant_admin

but I'm now passing the **account id** as a subdomain;
http://AccountName.example.com/

Is it possible to make the url work like this:
http://AccountName.example.com/tenant_admin ?

---

```
Routes.rb

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"


  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets

  resources :accounts do
    resources :tenant_admin
  end

  constraints(Subdomain) do
    match '/' => 'accounts#show'
  end

  root :to => "welcome#index"
```

Comment: You can do it. To see exactly how to do this in rails 3.x without using any additional plugins checkout this railscasts episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?autoplay=true

Comment: Thanks. I got that bit working. My real problem is routing the 3rd type of url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put your tenant routes under `resources :accounts` and `constraints(Subdomain)`. I don't recommend using copy and paste but a lambda instead.

```
tenant_routes = lambda do
  resources :tenant_admin
end

resources :accounts do
  tenant_routes.call
end

constraints(Subdomain) do
  tenant_routes.call
end
```